# Align text in the centre of an image slider

Tags: html, css

I have a `image` slider and I am trying to `align` some explanatory `text` in the `horizontal` and `vertical centre` of each image.

How can I archieve this in HTML/CSS?

Here is my Slider: [**jsbin**](http://jsbin.com/gabututociwe/1/)
// Note I edited ur jsbin - now the text is visible and the question clear.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Elaborate.

Comment: Not helping. Voting to close for completely unclear what you're asking. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a CSS class that looks like:

```
display:block;
line-height:*same as your slider height*;
margin:0 auto;
position:relative;
z-index:99;
```

and put within the slider. Some tweaks have to be made to that CSS but the basic idea remains.

Answer (score 0):

Use following HTML and CSS

```
<article>
<div class="text">hihihi</div>
<img alt="an interesting rock" src="http://placehold.it/300x300/123456/000000/&text=1">
</article>



.text {
    color: white;
    height: 300px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47%;
    width: 100%;
}

#slides article {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 25%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do two changes.

1. Add `position:relative` to the parent.

   ```
   #slides article
   {
     width:25%;
     float:left;
     position:relative;
   }
   ```
2. Add positions(top, left, bottom, right) to your `text` class.

   ```
    .text
    {
      position:absolute;
      display:table;
      width:100%;
      color:#fff;
      height:30px;
      top:0;
      bottom:0;
      right:0;
      left:0;
      margin:auto;
    }
   ```

The `display:table` property and fixing some small `height` with `margin:auto` will do the magic.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/oh2sy63v/)